# Update all SQL NULL values in multiple columns using Column level WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

We have a database with a bunch of wide tables (40-80 columns each) and just found a bug that introduced NULL values into about 500 of the records. The NULL values can appear in any of the columns (all are integer columns, see image below) but these NULL values are causing issues with one of our reporting systems that cannot be changed easily. We need to replace the NULL values with a specific static value (in this case 99), but since this change has to be made on a per-column basis for over 250 different columns I would rather not write individual TSQL scripts updating each column one by one.

My brain is too fried right now to think up a clever solution, so my question is how can I perform this task on all columns on a table (or better yet multiple tables) using a simple and readable SQL query. I can isolate the records easy enough using a chain of `WHERE (Answer_1 IS NULL) OR (Answer_2 IS NULL) OR ...` or even by AdministrationID numbers for each table, but this trick won't work when updating as where clause is per row not per column. Any advice?

Here is a sample query showing a few of the records from 4 different tables:
[image: Sample]

Comment: I guess I would add a not null constraint with a default 99 on each and every column?

Comment: I look at this and ask myself why the columns aren't the following: AdministrationID, InstrumentID, AnswerID, value. Heck, you could even add another id so that you can merge all those tables into 1...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There isn't any convention to this -- if you want to only process records where respective columns are NULL, you need to use:

```
WHERE Answer_1 IS NULL 
   OR Answer_2 IS NULL 
   OR ...
```

But you could use this in the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
   SET col1 = COALESCE(col1, 99),
       col2 = COALESCE(col2, 99),
       col3 = ...
```

The logic is that the value will be updated to 99 only if the column value is NULL, because of how COALESCE works--returning the first non-NULL value (processing the list provided from left to right).

Comment: +1 - I must be tired, I was trying to do this with a `CASE` statement... O_o

Comment: And on the bright side, the columns are all in `Answer_` format, so Greg should be able to bash out the scripts in Excel pretty quick

Answer (score 7):

Just poll the sys.columns table for each table and create some dynamic sql... It's brute force but it saves you from having to write all the t-sql out.

For example:

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME AS VARCHAR(255)

SET @TABLENAME = 'ReplaceWithYourTableName'

SELECT 'UPDATE ' + @TableName  + ' SET ' + CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(255)) + ' = 99 
 WHERE ' + CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(255)) + ' IS NULL'
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TABLENAME)
    AND system_type_id = 56 -- int's only
```

Comment: I partially agree with Ashish Patel on the ISNULL.  You should scrub the data for your reporting environment and provide the necessary defaults to simplify the reporting sql IMO.  I think the ISNULL is a scalar function to boot, which is equally bad on performance (I can't seem to be able to confirm this assumption via google searches :) ) If the columns shouldn't be NULL, then perhaps the schema should be changed to not allow NULL's or a default value get added at the database level.  Again, this is outside the scope of the question and probably just boils down to each shops coding standards.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have to do this all over the place i wrote some javascript to help you build the sql.  cut and paste this into your browsers address bar to get your sql.

```
javascript:sql='update your table set ';x=0;while(x <= 40){sql += 'answer_'+x+ ' = coalesce(answer_'+x+',99),\n';x++;};alert(sql);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the idea to manipulate the data itself for the purpose of reporting. If you change the NULL values to 99 to just to make your reporting easier then the I consider that data as corrupted. What if there are other consumer apart from reporting which need genuine data?

I would rather write an intelligent query for the report. For example, if you use ISNULL(columnname, 99), it would return 99 whenever the column value is NULL.

Comment: I would usually agree, but in this case the NULL values were added by mistake instead of using the correct value of 99. Also changing the reporting query is not an option as it is a proprietary reporting system.