# SQL NULL OUT OF MANY COLUMNS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have to take NULL values out of many columns. I have been doing some research but it tells me that I can do it for one column at a time and it will take to long to do. Is there a better way? The code I have right now is:

```
    Update table set column1 = 0 where column1 IS NULL
```

Any help or ideas will be helpful. Thanks, Michelle

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update all SQL NULL values in multiple columns using Column level WHERE clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938958/update-all-sql-null-values-in-multiple-columns-using-column-level-where-clause)

Comment: This might be a stupid question but im still trying to learn sql. I was told that IS NULL returns a boolean and does not replace a value, is that the same with coalesce?

Comment: Coalesce will return the first non-null value from left to right that are sent to it as parameters. If all values sent are null, it will return null. The question @minitech provided clearly illustrates this

Comment: IS NULL does return a boolean, but ISNULL(columnName, value) returns the value of the columnName column, or the "value" if columnName is null.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH! You have helped me tons!

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but why do you want, or rather, why do you NEED to change all your null values to 0? What benefit do you derive?

Comment: The reason why I need to do that is because if I add a number to a null it will just equal to null and I need it to equal a number. NULL + number = NULL

Comment: Instead of changing your data, you're probably better off updating your queries to use `ISNULL` in your computations, e.g. `select x=ISNULL(Column1,0)+@i`, etc. If you try to update your data, you'll create an additional future maintenance requirement, and all the potential problems that go with it, especially if your data is frequently updated.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want something like this.

> Update table set column1 = COALESCE(column1, 0), column2 = COALESCE(column2, 0) where column1 IS NULL or column2 IS NULL;

The COALESCE function will use the first number value that isn't null. This means that if column1 is null, 0 is used. But if column1 is null, 0 is used.

The OR statement would allow you to return any rows which have a null in either column1 or column2 and update them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a SSMS instance on me, or am I near a working db (I reinstalled my box just a while ago), but this is a great time (one of the very few) to use a cursor (since this seems to be a one-off request).  Forgive me if you get a syntax error here -- if someone sees an error, feel free to edit :)

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @colName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE my_cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('myTableName') AND name IN ('list', 'of', 'columns', 'you', 'care', 'about'); 

OPEN my_cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM my_cur INTO @colName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN    
    SET @sql = 'Update myTableName set ' + @colName +' = 0 where ' + @colName + ' IS NULL';
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
    FETCH NEXT FROM my_cur INTO @colName;
END

CLOSE my_cur;
DEALLOCATE my_cur;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you want to remove all nulls from a table crossing many different columns? If auditing is not a problem, then you could just do something like this:

```
UPDATE [TABLE]
SET Column1 = 
    CASE 
        WHEN Column1 IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE Column1
    END,
    Column2 = 
    CASE
        WHEN Column2 IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE Column2
    END, ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISNULL option

```
UPDATE table
   SET column1 = ISNULL(column1, 0)
      ,column2 = ISNULL(column2, 0)
 WHERE column1 IS NULL 
    OR column2 IS NULL;
```