# How do I remove null from table columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have a database table populated with 10k rows of data. A great deal of those rows have null values in specific columns. How do I replace this null value with for instance the empty string for a string column?

I'm looking for the *easiest* way to do this since this operation will only need to be performed *once*.

**What I have tried:**

```
UPDATE tablename set mycolumn='' where mycolumn is null;
```

This gives me the following error:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

I am not the administrator of the database, so I cannot disable safe mode.

```
UPDATE tablename set mycolumn=''
  where Id in (SELECT Id FROM tablename where mycolumn is null);
```

This gives me the following error:

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'tablename' for update in FROM clause.

---

**Note:**

In the examples above I have substituted the real tablename and column-name with placeholders.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update all SQL NULL values in multiple columns using Column level WHERE clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938958/update-all-sql-null-values-in-multiple-columns-using-column-level-where-clause)

Comment: Do the opposite, replace empty strings with NULL!

Comment: Yes, the requirement is odd. Why do you want to replace `NULL` values with empty stirngs at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)

Comment: @TedHopp: he has mentioned that he can't disable safe mode.

Comment: @FilipeFerreira: that's not a duplicate because OP knows how to update null values with an empty string. The issue is that he can't do that with safe mode and he can't disable safe-mode.

Comment: This seems to be a client, not a server restriction. Did you try to toggle the safe mode option?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Some of the answers there (including the accepted answer) show solutions that do not involve disabling safe mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
UPDATE tablename set mycolumn = '' 
where Id IN (select Id from (select Id from tablename where mycolumn IS NULL) as x)
```

But why do you want to replace `NULL` values with empty strings at all?

If you could disable safe mode [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench) would be a duplicate.

Comment: This worked for me. The reasons for the replacement of null was testing.

Comment: @transporter_room_3: so [Andy's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31335447/284240) didn't work? I was curious, i'm mainly  using sql-server so i couldn't test it.

Comment: No, I get this error: (Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column) which is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the table and set NOT NULL for the columns.

And you can also simply do the following:

> To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: That won't work if the column contains `null` values already. It violates the constraint and the data will be invalid according to the scheme, so you should first update, then set the constraint.

Comment: set default as '' and set not null in table defination by altering the table , it will surely works

Comment: Okay, but that wasn't you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it like:

```
 UPDATE tablename set mycolumn='' where mycolumn is null and Id is not null;
```

This actually doesn't change anything in update logic (since ID is primary key and can't be null) and it uses key column in where clause.